# webdriverIO - Unhandled promise rejection: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, webdriver-io

I'm learning UI testing with Jasmine & WebdriverIO. I use it with NodeJS.
I have the next test code:

```js
const projectsPage = require('../../lib/pages/projects.page');
const by = require('selenium-webdriver').By;

describe('Projects page', () => {
  it('Search google', async() => {
    await projectsPage.navigateTo();
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
      expect(title).toBe('Google');
    });
    driver.findElement(by.name('q')).sendKeys('test');
  })
});
```

When I run it, I receive the error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628411 (3324f4c8be9ff2f70a05a30ebc72ffb013e1a71e),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86_64)
```

But the code below performs successfully:

```js
describe('Projects page', () => {
  it('Search google', async() => {
    await projectsPage.navigateTo();
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
      expect(title).toBe('Google');
    });
    driver.findElement(by.name('q'))
  })
});
```

Where I was wrong?

Comment: just a quick question, have you tried using `await driver.findElement(by.name('q')).then(element => element.sendKeys('test'));`

Comment: Hi Verrom, Just wondering is this for `webdriver.io` or for `seleniumWebdriver.js`. My understanding is the `by` class is not used in `webdriver.io`. Just to ensure your question is posted with correct Tags.

Comment: @corschdi I didn't try it. Thanks a lot, it helped!
Could you create an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `findElement` and `sendKeys` also return promises, you'll have to await the methods as well:

```
await driver.findElement(by.name('q')).then(element => element.sendKeys('test'));
```

Comment: The `then` function adds another promise to the chain. Since the original test function is async and needs to wait for the `then` function to complete, `await` is required here.

Answer (score 0):

Your test ended before the code really runs, you should wait for each async statements

```
const projectsPage = require('../../lib/pages/projects.page');
const by = require('selenium-webdriver').By;

describe('Projects page', () => {
  it('Search google', async() => {
    await projectsPage.navigateTo();
    const title = await driver.getTitle();
    expect(title).toBe('Google');
    const q = await driver.findElement(by.name('q'));
    await q.sendKeys('test');
  })
});
```